# Django post request data outputs as none

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the value of bally and ballx to output with my post request (without using any forms as a project requirement), 
I have managed to get post requests going through without the use of a form, however the info out puts as none bally: None ballx: None, I feel like im quite close very new to python. Where am I going wrong

here is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from pong.models import SimpleBot

def home(request, template='index.html'):
    axis = HttpResponse(play(request))
    return render(request, template, {})


def bot(request):
    ballx = request.GET.get('ballx')
    bally = request.GET.get('bally')
    paddley = request.GET.get('paddley')
    court = {'ballx': ballx, 'bally': bally, 'paddley': paddley}
    data = {
      'up': SimpleBot.simple_bot(court),
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)

def play(request):
    ballx = request.POST.get('ballx')
    bally = request.POST.get('bally')
    court = {'ballx ': ballx, 'bally ': bally }
    print(court)
    return HttpResponse(court)
```

template/index.html

```
{% load static from static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Pong</title>
  </head>
  <h1>Pong<h1>
  <body>
   <canvas id='pong' width='600' height='400'></canvas>
   <script src={% static "pong.js" %}></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pong/', include('pong.urls')),
    path('', include('pong.urls')),
]
```

Edit - Now can display hardcoded values after a couple changes now trying to get ballx and bally to display
models.py

```
from django.db import models

class SimpleBot(models.Model):

    @classmethod
    def simple_bot(request, court):
        return court["bally"] > court["paddley"]

    @classmethod
    def post_bot(request, court):
        return court['ballx']
```

new views.py

```
def play(request):
    ballx = request.POST.get('ballx')
    bally = request.POST.get('bally')
    court = {'ballx ': ballx, 'bally ': bally }
    print(court)
    data = {
      'ballx': SimpleBot.post_bot(court),
      'bally': 'hello'
```

Comment: do you send `ballx` and `bally` in request body for POST request? @JBDR

Comment: where you use your view can you give also those stuff

Comment: Show your form in template

Comment: @MehaParekh ive checked this and have now changed some things will post them I can now get hard coded values to display off my post request So now trying to get actual ballx bally to display

Comment: sure! You can use Postman for making requests! @JBDR

Comment: @MehaParekh posted updates to code, Will look into Postman

Comment: ok, I'll have look at this! Postman link : `https://www.postman.com/`